# Prime numbers in Fermat's little theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

Consider prime numbers $a$ and $p$.

It is known  according to Fermat's little theorem   (FLT) that the congruence $a^{p-1}  \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$  holds for any prime $a$ and $p$.

From this we have that there are infinitely many numbers of  form $a^m$ which are congruent to $1$ as any power   $(a^{p-1})^k$ is congruent to $1$ if only $a^{p-1}$ is congruent.

The question arises however whether a number $m=p-1$ appearing in FLT is the **smallest  number** (obviously excluding $a^0=1$) which satifies $a^m  \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$ ?

I've made some experimental analysis taking into account powers of $a=2$ and sequence of prime numbers $p=5,7,11,13,17, 19 , \dots$.

I will name prime numbers $p$ for which equality above is satisfied when there is **no less** number $m$ than $p-1$ that $2^m  \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$ proper FLT prime numbers - if it happens that however there is a   number $m<p-1$   when $2^m  \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$ is satisfied I will name such number $p$ improper FLT number  (if there is more official terminology let me know) and number $m$ initial number for the given $p$.

Having made calculations I received following numbers $p$ for powers  of **two**  congruent to $ 1 \pmod {p}$:

Proper LFT numbers:
$5(4),11(10),13(12),19(18),29(28),37(36),53(52),59(58) \dots$

Improper LFT numbers:
$7 (3), 17 (8), 23(11), 31(5),41(20),43(14), 47(23)\dots$

Here in brackets smallest exponents $m$ (named as initial numbers) for satysfying formula $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$ are given. 
For example $2^8\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.

Evidently initial numbers    for improper FLT numbers are divisors of $p-1$ what is intuitively expected but  why exactly such value not other ?
(see $5$ for $31$, not for example $10$ or see $14$ for $43$ not $7$) it's hard to say.

My question:

- is it any method to discern proper and improper FLT numbers?
- if we are able to recognize that a given prime number is FLT improper
  can we also say what is an initial number associated with it?

Comment: Perhaps you like this exploration of the same question like yours but a little broader http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thank you very much, very interesting paper. Here it is even used the abbrevation FLT but .. for Fermat's Last Theorem :)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Coincidentally abbreviation FLT fits to  Fermat's Little Theorem and Fermat's Last Theorem at the same time. Maybe solution for this terminology ambiguity would be to use name Flitt and Flast for numbers in these theorems.

Comment: Dear Widawensen - that is a really scurrile and funny idea! I'll consider this for some nice moment....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are investigating whether the number $2$ is a "primitive root" modulo $p$. Every number $a=1,2,\ldots,p-1$ has an "order" mod $p$, which is the smallest power of $a$ that is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. A primitive root is a number whose order is $p-1$. The fact that every prime number has a primitive root is a non-trivial result.

Once we know that every prime has a primitive root, how do we predict which number(s) will be primitive roots, and which ones won't? This is hard, and there isn't a simple answer. We can say *how many* primitive roots there are for a given prime $p$, and once we find one, it's a simple matter to list the others. However, finding the first one is not something that we have a formula for.

I recommend reading up on primitive roots, and if you know some abstract algebra, studying the structure of the "units group" modulo $p$ (or, for even more fun, modulo $n$ for any natural number $n$.) Here's a starting point: [*Primitive root* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)

In any event, keep reading and asking great questions like this one about number theory! There is no limit to the joy you will find there. :)

Comment: There is no formula ? I'm a little disappointed.. my knowledge of abstract algebra is very basic... I was thinking that this kind of problem belongs rather to the number theory ... thank you for the encouragement ... and starting point..

Comment: Oh, it belongs to number theory, but number theory provides the motivation for much abstract algebra. Some have said that finite group theory is nothing more than number theory.

Comment: Here's a taste: The number 29 is prime. We have 29-1=28, and there are 12 numbers between 1 and 28 that are relatively prime to 28. Therefore, 29 has 12 primitive roots, because the numbers 1-28 form a cyclic multiplicative group, and any generator of that group is a primitive root. If you find one primitive root, say '$g$', then raising $g$ to any power relatively prime to 28 will give you another primitive root!

Comment: That's interesting, unexpected for me connection ..

Comment: Ok, I see this but why some prime numbers behave differently in Fermat's little theorem than others ? .. some are the smallest possibilities for satisfying congruence to $1$, other not..

Comment: They don't. Every prime *has* primitive roots. What varies is whether the number $2$ happens to be one. Repeat your calculations for $a=3$, and you'll get a different set of primes. Note that, for your "improper LFT numbers" the power of $2$ that works is always a factor of $p-1$.

Comment: Ok. some calculations for a=3    "congruencies  3 ^  to 1 i (Mod j)"
 3^ 4 (mod  5)                           3^ 6 (mod  7)              3^ 12 (mod  7)                     3^ 5 (mod  11)              3^ 10 (mod  11)              3^ 15 (mod  11)              3^ 3 (mod  13)      3^ 6 (mod  13)       3^ 9 (mod  13)                           3^ 15 (mod  13)              3^ 18 (mod  13)            3^ 16 (mod  16)              3^ 16 (mod  17)              3^ 18 (mod  19)            3^ 11 (mod  23)    ....

Comment: Once you have $3^k\equiv 1$, you're going to have $3^{nk}\equiv 1$ for every integer $n$, because $3^{nk}=(3^k)^n\equiv 1^n=1$.

Comment: As you can see, the prime $p=7$ was improper for $a=2$, but proper for $a=3$. Conversely, $p=11$ is proper for $a=2$, but improper for $a=3$. On the other hand, $p=5$ is proper for both, and $p=23$ is improper for both. If you check $a=5$, you'll find that $p=23$ is finally proper for some base :)

Comment: Yes, I know that... from this follows that are infinitely many such congruent to 1 numbers... however sometimes this initial number is not a number calculated from FLT (p-1) but some divisor of p-1

Comment: The numbers that are congruent to $1$ for a power less than $p-1$ are not primitive roots. Neither $2$ nor $3$ is a primitive root for $p=23$, but $5$ is one. You have discovered that $2$ is a primitive root for $p=5, 11, 13, 19, \ldots$

Comment: You correctly noticed...Number 7 is improper for a =2 and proper for a=3 ... and there is really no method how to know it...

Comment: None. That's why people make tables of these things for reference.

Comment: Is there any hope to discover a method  in the future? What do you think? or this is problem unsolvable by its nature...

Comment: Whew.... I really don't know. Pretty sure it's not an area of current research, although there are related conjectures that people are working on. Using your terminology, for any $a>1$ that is not a perfect square, are there infinitely many primes that are LFT-proper? Artin's conjecture surmises that there are.

Comment: Now I guess it's time for me to study  the paper from the starting point... maybe then I will add something  to this problem..

Comment: I have found it.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots    I will study it..

Comment: It's turned out that improper FLT listed above  are so-called primes with primitive root 2 which are listed  as [A001122 OEIS sequence][1].
 
  [1]: https://oeis.org/A001122